# exporting DDL of all views Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, oracle-9i

How can I go about exporting DDL of all my schema views in single .sql file ?
I've read there is a function `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`   But I can't figure out how to use it for my case.

I know how to do this for one view (Oracle Entreprise Manager->MySchema->Views->Selecting my view->show object DDL->Save..)

I'm using SQL*Plus

Answer (score 1):

You can `SPOOL` the output into a file:

```
SPOOL 'C:\Temp\all_views.sql';
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', view_name) FROM user_views;
SPOOL OFF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for DBMS_METADATA.GET_DLL:

```
set long 200000 pages 0 lines 150
spool vw.sql
select 
   dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('VIEW',u.view_name,DECODE(u.owner,'SYS','',owner)) 
from 
   all_views u
where 
   owner IN ('HR','SCOTT') 
order by owner,view_name ;
spool off
```

You can either include the schemas you are interested in or exclude the schemas you do not want in the "owner IN" clause.

Comment: Message from 7 years in the future: what is accomplished by `DECODE(u.owner,'SYS','',owner)`? If the owner of the view is SYS, it omits that from schema parameter of the GET_DDL function?

Answer (score 0):

I've found `all_mviews` view helpful. With `name` and `text` fields i could easily generate create statement for all necessary views without unnecessary information. I've used Java and JDBC to write to file, but i think you also can do it with spool in sqlplus.